# SUMIF and SUBTOAL EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

Is there anyway in Excel to combine `SUBTOTAL` and `SUMIF`

- I have one column with a description in
- I have one column with dates in
- I have a final column which contains the calculation.

I want to subtotal (when the date filter is applied) all values that reference the column range which contain plain text words such as "Trading"

My `SUMIF` works fine on its own it's just I want to `SUBTOTAL` when a particular date range or any filter on the table is selected.

Appreciate any help on this one

`=SUBTOTAL(9,(SUMIF(E4:E200,"Trading",S4:S200)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of SUMPRODUCT, SUBTOTAL, and OFFSET...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E4:E200="Trading"),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(S4:S200,ROW(S4:S200)-ROW(S4),0,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you Domenic that works perfectly, I would never have got that in a 100 years of trying so thank you so much. I understand it now I have applied it apart from the -- thanks once again.